# SwipeRefreshLayout with vertical view pager to only refresh on the topmost fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, vertical-scrolling, swiperefreshlayout

I've tried to implement `swiperefreshlayout` in my code but it keeps refreshing the entire pager instead of just refreshing when i'm on the first `Fragment` i.e the 0th `Fragment`.
I tried setting refresh to false as shown, but the loader still appears, and doesn't reset when I go back to the 0th `Fragment` again.
On setting `swiperefreshlayout.enable(false)`, I can't refresh it anywhere.
Can anyone suggest an alternative?
This is my `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLinearLayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <lbbdapp.littleblackbook.com.littleblackbook.Support.VerticalViewPager
                android:id="@+id/verticalViewPager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my activity:

```
public class FeedActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

PageAdapter mPageAdapter;
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
ProgressDialog prog;
ViewPager pager;
String article_id;
private float x1, x2;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

ArrayList<FragmentObject> mObjectsDataList;
ArrayList<ArticleObject> mArticleDataList=new ArrayList<ArticleObject>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.feed_layout);
    mObjectsDataList = new ArrayList<FragmentObject>();

    DataFetcherTask myTask = new DataFetcherTask();
    myTask.execute();

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_purple,
            android.R.color.darker_gray);
    pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.verticalViewPager);



    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            if(pager.getCurrentItem()==0) {
                Log.wtf("current item is 0", "0");
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                Log.wtf("Swiping", "Refreshing");
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        DataFetcherTask myTask = new DataFetcherTask();
                        myTask.execute();
                    }
                }, 3000);

            }
            else{
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        }

    });


}
```

This is my vertical `ViewPager`:

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // The majority of the magic happens here
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            view.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending SwipeRefesh over ViewGroup use it inside the each Fragment of ViewPager.
Once this is resolved now you need to check scroll down gesture of ViewPager and SwipeRefresh.

```
public class NEWSwipeRefresh extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private View mTargetView;

    public NEWSwipeRefresh(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public NEWSwipeRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setTarget(View view) {
        mTargetView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (mTargetView instanceof YOURVIEW) {
            final StaggeredGridView absListView = (YOURVIEW)mTargetView;
            return absListView.getChildCount() > 0
                    && (absListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0 || absListView
                            .getChildAt(0).getTop() < absListView
                            .getPaddingTop());
        } else {
            return super.canChildScrollUp();
        }
    }

}
```

Normally swipe refresh returns -1 and it gives swipe gesture to it's parent now I have overridden it here for listview/gridview so that it can check for visible items, if it is on top then it will give swipe to parent or otherwise it will give it to children.

Comment: Could you give me a sample? How do I check for just a particular swipe? My activity allows normal swipes too.

Comment: How to detect vertical swipe down of vertical view pager?

Comment: @SimranBakshi I have written an example of using SwipeRefresh with listview/gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was trying to figure this out since few days and it's quite simple. Just put the `SwipeRefreshLayout` as the parent element of `ViewPager` and just disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` on the particular fragment using `OnPageChangeListener` as follows:

```
//  viewpager change listener
 OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {

     //for the 0th pos disable SwipeRefreshLayout;
     if(position != 0){
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
     }else swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);

  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

  }};
```